# Deleting all elements that contain '$string' from arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to delete all items from `$array` which contain `$str`. `$str='foo'`.

I want the elements which are after the deleted elements to 'shift back'.

For example:
    `$array = array('1', '0', '  ', '1')` 
I want the `$array[3]` to lose its content, and receive the content of `$array[4]`, which will be deleted.

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried in order to do this? I mean certainly you have at least tried a `foreach()` along with `strpos()` right?

Comment: you mean you want to remove the items from the array?

Comment: with the `foreach()` and `strpos()` i could not remove them alond their 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try array_filter

```
$array=array('a' => '123', 'b' => 34);
$str = '2';
var_dump(
    array_filter(
    $array, function($element) use ($str) {if(strpos($element, $str) === false) return true;}
    )
);
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(34)
}
```

If you want replace $str, you should use array_map

```
var_dump(array_map(
    function($element) use ($str) { return str_replace($str, '', $element);}, $array)
);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(2) "13"
  ["b"]=>
  string(2) "34"
}
```

Final solution for next condition "I want the elements which are after the deleted elements to 'shift back'."

```
$values = array_filter($array, function($element) use ($str) {if(strpos($element, $str) === false) return true;});
$keys = array_slice(array_keys($array), 0, count($values));
var_dump (array_combine($keys, $values));
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(34)
}
```

Comment: Or, instead of testing the cause and returning `true` if it's true, just do: `return (strpos($element, $str) === false);`

Comment: yes, this would be good, but I want the `array['a']` to become `int(34)`.

Comment: thank you! I tried this in my code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
foreach($array as $v => $a) {
    if($a == 'foo') {
        unset($array[$v]);
    }
}
```

(This of course assumes that the string consists of only 'foo').

Comment: `foreach`-ing by reference does not work like you seem to think it does... [unsetting one reference does not unset them all](http://codepad.org/cTJzUHzF).

Comment: @Wrikken My bad, thanks for pointing that out.  I had remembered using that method for something different in the past (months ago).  I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = preg_grep("/{$str}/i", $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```